# getting no result in using @input in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I know it has been asked before, and there is alot of answer if I google. I did. I dont know what i am doing wrong here. I simply want to pass a value from a component to another. here is what i did: 
1. here is the parent html:

```
  <app-dpedit [parentValue]= "testValue"> </app-dpedit>
```

testValue is a string variable initiated with a dummy string in parent.ts

in child, I have the following:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dpedit',
  templateUrl: './dpedit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dpedit.component.css'],


})
export class DPEditComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() parentValue:string;
```

if i log the parenValue i will get "undefined"

I have also tried to use "inputs : ['parentValue'] instead of the @Input, same issue.
please help me figure out the problem.

**EDIT** entire child ts file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators,FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

import {GetDataProcessingService} from "../../../service/getServices/get-data-processing.service"
import {ProfileComponent} from "../profile/profile.component"
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dpedit',
  templateUrl: './dpedit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dpedit.component.css']

})
export class DPEditComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() parentValue:string;

//region variables
  currentURl;
  dataProcessingEditForm: FormGroup;
  formValid=false;
  theDP={};
  yesNoArray=["Yes","No"];
  yesNoFlag=false;
  _ref:any;
//endregion

 constructor(
    private getDataProcessingService: GetDataProcessingService,

    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.dataProcessingEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      legalReference: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      Title: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      Description: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      dataProcessor: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      dataController: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      timeEstimation:['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      justifyDUration:['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],



      ExistingRecipientName:['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      ExistingRecipientLocation:['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],

      RecipientYesNo:['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      recipient:[],
      addRecipient:[],


      DSofSectors: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.requiredTrue
      ])],
      DTofSectors: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.requiredTrue //RequiredTrue needs to be used for the checkbox so that in case of checking and unchecking will work fine
      ])],
      typeOfProcessing:['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.requiredTrue
      ])]

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   console.log("here ===>  " + this.parentValue)



  }

}
```

Comment: where did you log the parentValue post the code

Comment: in the ngOnInit. I also tried to use {{parentValue}} in the HTML, as well

Comment: You need to define the input as `@Input()`, not just `@Input`

Comment: i updated the  question, Input is executable in my code. here i missed it.  sorry for that

Comment: `testValue` is variable or just plain string?

Comment: if it is string, you need to surround it with single quotes when using property binding, or drop brackets to bind just the string.

Comment: maybe you should prepare stackblitz example. just a wild guess -- i see `parenValue` in your question, while the name should be `parentValue` -- maybe just a typo in your code?

Comment: yea, that is  a typo

Comment: You need to post the full code here otherwise I can not see where you reference this variable and where you log the variable. Cuz the problem must be in there. Also please notice if you `console.log()` in the constructor, it won't work as Input is not binded on that stage.

Comment: The problem will be rather in your parent component, your child component controller looks good imo. Complete stackblitz example with your issue would help...

Answer (score 0):

The [`Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator needs to be executed:

```
export class DPEditComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() parentValue:string;
}
```

Also you should use double quotes as @Harunur Rashid already suggested (but that should not be required I guess).

If you try to pass there simple string, you need to add single quotes or use string binding (drop brackets):

```
<app-dpedit [parentValue]="'testValue'"></app-dpedit>
// or
<app-dpedit parentValue="testValue"></app-dpedit>
```

Comment: updated the question. () was missing here not in the code

Comment: testValue is a string variable initiated with a dummy string in parent.ts